# Firebase initializing into a deleted project, with no firebase.json file

Tags: html, firebase

I'm running into a very annoying problem with firebase. So, I'm trying to initiate a firebase project, but it's trying to initialize it into a deleted project. This is a new folder, with ***no*** firebase.json I can delete; I'm trying to figure out what to do.

What I've tried:

- Restarting PC
- Restarting VS
- Making a new folder
- Initializing a project with different files.
- Logging in/out.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `~/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json` -- the Firebase CLI keeps directory-based project mappings there and you may have a stale one that needs to be cleaned up. Otherwise, the CLI also looks up the directory structure for `firebase.json` so make sure you don't have a `firebase.json` in a parent directory somewhere.